# What does sed -i '/$$wf_cdc=/c\$$wf_cdc='"$1"'' mean?

Tags: sed

I have this script with just one line, but I could not understand what it really does:

```
sed -i '/$$wf_cdc=/c\$$wf_cdc='"$1"'' /Infa_sharedBDE/PARAMS/pf_CREDITO_CDC.cfg
```

It should replace creating a copy of the `pf_CREDITI_CDC.cfg` file, but 
what does this command do?

```
'/$$wf_cdc=/c\$$wf_cdc='"$1"''
```

What is `$$`?

Answer (score 0):

`$$` is used literally here. The command does the following:

- `'/$$wf_cdc=/` is a line address: if a line contains the string `$$wf_cdc=`, then ...
- `c\$$wf_cdc='"$1"''` could also be written `c $$wf_cdc='"$1"''` (at least in GNU sed): it replaces the pattern space (the current line) with `\$$wf_cdc='"$1"''`. Personally, I'd escape `$` both times to make sure it's not interpreted as end-of-line anchor, but sometimes you get away without it.

  - `'"$1"''` is the first positional parameter properly quoted: end single quote of the sed command, then insert `$1` in double quotes, then finish rest of single quoted string (empty, in this case, and could be dropped in my opinion).

All in all, this will be called in a function or script, find the line containing `$$wf_cdc=` and replace it with `$$wf_cdc=<parameter>`, where `<parameter>` is supplied to the script or function as its first argument.

The `-i` flag replaces the file being edited "in place", i.e., makes and modifies a temporary copy and then renames that copy to the name of the original file.